# Is empty set a proper subset of any set, except itself?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

First, terminology: I am studying in Russian, and there is a term *собственное подмножество*, that, as I understand means **proper subset** (literally - "own" subset), and *несобственное подмножество*, which is opposite, like **"nonproper" subset**.

---

I read a book, and there was written that any set has at least two "nonproper" subsets - itself and an empty set.

At the same time, definition of the proper subset: *if A is a subset of B, and there is an element in B, that A does not contain, then A is a proper subset of B*.

From the definition above, "non-proper" subset is indeed a set itself, but an empty subset, is a set, that does not contain some element from it's superset (if it is not an empty set).

Of course, it is also seems wrong that empty set is a subset of any (non-empty) set, because all of subset elements should be at superset, but it at least perceived less wrong, while the fact that empty set is "nonproper" subset of any set is just a violation of the definition.

Same statements are written in Russian Wikipedia [subset article](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE#%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE):

> Any set B, through all own subsets contains itself and an empty
> subset. B set itself and an empty subset are called **nonproper
> subsets**, the rest subsets are called **proper**

But in English version of [subset article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset) is written opposite:

> ∅ is a subset of any set X and a **proper subset** of any set except
> itself

So, which sources are wrong?

---

### Prove

• If ∅ is nonproper subset of X, hence, X=∅, which wrong (only if superset X is not an empty set, of course).

• If ∅ ⊆ B (nonproper), then B ∩ ∅ should be B, which is wrong.

Comment: I think "proper" in this sense can be ambiguous. A proper sub-object (a proper ideal of a ring, for example, or a proper subgroup of a group) normally means not the whole object and not the trivial object. But certainly in English it is possible that a proper subgroup is simply less than the whole group. I would counsel making sure you check definitions in each case.

Comment: @MarkBennet, this is exactly what it means in Russian, and, I assume in any other language - proper, means the part of something, not the whole something. If "whole something", then "nonproper". So I do not think **proper** can be ambiguous because of that, and, generally because of strict definition

Comment: My point (as a comment) is that in English usage the word "proper" is used in different contexts with different meanings - both "not the whole thing" and "non-trivial". In such a case it is worth checking for any ambiguity: it is generally obvious what is meant and whether "trivial" cases are included or excluded.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on what is meant with "proper". If it means "nontrivial" , the empty set is also ruled out. But "proper" can also mean : "a subset different from the set itself" (which is an obvious subset) , allowing also the empty set. Personally , I would prefer the first definition in analogy to a factor of a number , where we usually also mean a nontrivial factor ($1$ and the number itself are excluded).

Comment: I do not think it should depend. While the definition of **"nonproper"** is debatable, the **proper subset** is straightly defined, and same as in English, as well as in Russian: all elements of proper subset are at its superset, but the superset has element that is not at proper subset

Comment: So, from this definition there can be only one "nonproper" subset

Comment: If you agree that "nonproper" is debatable , then "proper" is debatable as well , since the only reasonable interpretation of "nonproper" is "not proper" , the opposite of "proper".

Comment: Not agree, since "nonproper" in current discussion is not independent, and exists only as the opposite to something independent. If we consider something we know good, and then, during another consideration will doubt about something derivative from it, it does not mean that the original one is also what we should doubt of, a priori.

Comment: I agree that $1$ and $n$ are trivial factors of $n$. However, $1$ is a proper factor (for  $n>1$), while $n$ itself is not.

Comment: Well, at least one other user claims that "proper" is ambigious. Where is your reference ? And if you think there is no room for the discussion, I do not understand the question.

Comment: "proper" is tied to sub, not to set. Non (proper sub) set may mean a set containing a subset and something else, eg your grandmother. Its  a linguistic term coned in German as "eigentlich" in the sense of "original"  against "uneigentlich" as an sophisticated extension to the original meaning of a term.