# superset and proper superset

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A = \{a\}$ and $a = \{1\}$. So $A = \{\,\{1\}\,\}$.

I'm struggling a bit with the concept of the proper superset.

$$\text{Statement 1:} \quad A \supseteq \{1\}$$
$$\text{Statement 2:} \quad A \supset \{1\}$$

Which of these statements is correct?

Comment: None of them. $\{\,\{1\}\,\}$ is a subset (but not a proper subset) of $A.$ But both statement $1$ and statement $2$ are false. $\{1\}\ $ is a member of $A,$ not a subset of it. Although I could be wrong, as it's a bit confusing with all the curly brackets.

Answer (score 2):

A set $X$ is called a superset of set $Y$ if every element of $Y$ is also an element of $X$.
Consider the sets $A=\{\{1\}\}$ and $a=\{1\}$. Is $1$ (a member of $a$) an element of the set $A$ (which only contains the element $a=\{1\}$)? No! Therefore $A$ cannot be a superset of $a$.

A proper superset of a set $X$ is a superset that isn't the same as $X$ (convince yourself that $X$ is a superset of $X$). Thus naturally $A$ cannot be a proper superset of $a$ either. Thus both statements are wrong.

Comment: Tangentially relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4766649/1055916